# Fit to button width

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `DockPanel` which is 200 pixels wide. Inside this `DockPanel` I have a `Button`. The button fits perfectly to the width. However, inside the button, I have a `Border`, which I would like to fit to the `Button` width (so that it fills the `Button`). How can I do this? Normally I would change the container, but since the container is a `Button`, that doesn't really seem like an option. My best bet was to use `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`, but this doesn't seem to work.

**My XAML:**

```
<DockPanel Height="50" Width="200">

    <Button
        DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
        BorderThickness="0"                    
        Background="Transparent" 
        Padding="0">

        <Border
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            BorderBrush="DimGray"
            BorderThickness="1"
            CornerRadius="5"
            Background="LightSalmon"
            Height="30">

            <TextBlock
                Text="Let me in" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

        </Border>

    </Button>

    <!-- This empty border creates a blank vertical space of 20 px above the button -->
    <Border DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" />
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Set the Button's `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch`.

Comment: @Clemens that doesn't change anything. The button is already fitting the width (200 px). It is the border, inside the button, which is not fitting the width.

Comment: Works fine for me. Sure you've set it on the Button?

Comment: Ah, I read your comment too fast (didn't notice the "content" part). I wasn't aware of that property, thank you! If you make it an actual answer, I can accept it (make sure to stress the "content part", for other noobs, like me :-))